# Modernizing pages: webpartmapping.xml not found

Tags: sharepoint-online, asp.net

I want to modernize site pages by following the .NET version of this [Microsoft Blog: Modernize your SharePoint Pages](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/modernize-your-sharepoint-pages/)
I added the nugget package, I use a SharePoint Online Url.

When I get to the code

```
PageTransformator pageTransformator = new PageTransformator(ctx);
```

I get the error

> Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\webpartmapping.xml'.

Altough I have the webpartmapping.xml in the project.

[image: Webpartmapping file in solution explorer]

and the webpartmapping properties are "copy always".
[image: Webpartmapping properties]

Any idea why I get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Thinking about it, it was a stupid question :P

Just took the file from my project, found at the location in the file's properties:
[image: Location of file]

and moved it to the location given in the error.

**Tadaah, it works.**

Although I expected it to do be moved automatically. Maybe because I don't have Visual Studio opened as Administrator (for reasons)